# Unable to send mail from Linux, works perfectly with windows

Tags: php, linux, email

I am using the following code to sent mail for a contact form. The mail works perfectly when using a windows server setup with xampp, but fails in Linux server RHEL 5.
I am getting "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host". I tried telnet the host from terminal. It is getting connected

```
public function smtpmailer($to,$cc, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) {
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->IsHTML();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = 'XXX@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'XXXXXXXX';
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
        $mail->AddCC($cc);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
```

While Debugging is set to 1 I am getting the following error

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
>   SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as if name resolving is not working. Check `/etc/resolv.conf`, it should contain a line like this:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Replace `8.8.8.8` by the IP of your desired nameserver.

Comment: The nameserver is given with a valid dns ip and I am able to browse pages and getting a ping in the server too

Comment: Are you able to lookup `smtp.gmail.com`? Try it via shell like this: `dig smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: Yes, I was able to do the       dig smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Is `/etc/resolv.conf` readable by world? What happens if you add `smtp.gmail.com` to `/etc/hosts`? Also, try to restart Apache. Maybe he is still using an old DNS.

Comment: That was it; I restarted Apache and it's working now. Thank You